# Does OpenJDK 7 support the hard float abi?

Tags: java

I know that Oracle JDK 7 and 8 support hard float ABI on ARM Units. But I haven´t found any information about the OpenJDK 7 supporting this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The clear implication of [this page](https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/OpenJFX/Cross+Building+for+ARM+Hard+Float) is that you can cross-compile OpenJDK 8 with Hard Float support. (See the example commands towards the end ...)

The page doesn't mention specific Java versions, so given that Oracle JDK 7 supports it it is likely that OpenJDK 7 will as well.